# Construction of a cauchy sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, cauchy-sequences

> Construct a cauchy sequence $(r_n)$ such that $r_n\in\mathbb{Q}$ $ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ , $(r_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence but $\lim_{n \to \infty}r_n $ does not belong to $\mathbb{Q}$

Can anyone let me know where to start? I'm completely at sea with this so just an idea of the bare essentials to prove this would be helpful.

Comment: Every convergent sequence is also a Cauchy sequence. So it's enough to find a sequence in $\mathbb Q$ that has a limit that does not belong to $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: $$r_n=1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\cdots+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n$$

Comment: How do we know it's this sequence? Can it be any other? If so how do we know how to form one?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** Consider $r_n = \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \in \Bbb Q$.

Comment: So we can take any convergent sequence whose limit isn't rational?

Comment: Can't it simply be $r_n=\frac{1}{n}$ ?

Comment: @Paradox101 no, $1/n$ converges to $0\in \Bbb Q$.

Comment: @Paradox101 and yes any convergent sequence is also a Cauchy sequence (in $\Bbb R$ at least).

Comment: Oh ok.But looking at the question there can be a number of possibilities for the answer. How do we know how to form the sequence?Are we supposed to use dedekind cuts? I still don't understand how to go from here

Comment: @Paradox101 yes there can be many possibility. For example, one construction of $\Bbb R$ is to say that $\Bbb R$ is the set of limit points of Cauchy sequences in $\Bbb Q$. This reflects the fact that any irrational number can be expressed as the limit of a Cauchy sequence of rational sequence. The sequence I proposed you here is just an example. However, it is a very classical example. Do you recognize this sequence? Dedekind cut is not *directly* needed to prove that the sequence $r_n$ proposed above solves your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Pick your favorite real number. Call it $r$. Then consider the sequence of intervals 
$I_n = (r-\frac{1}{n}, r+\frac{1}{n})$  for $n=1, 2, ...$

Use the axiom of choice to choose a rational number from each interval. The resulting sequence converges to $r$.

Alternatively you can look at the decimal expansion of $r$ and take a sequence ${r_n}$ where $r_n$ is just the first $n$ terms after the decimal point.

Comment: Surely axiom of choice is overkill here: number the rationals, $q_1, q_2, \ldots$, then let $q_n$ be the rational in $I_n$ with the lowest indexing number.

Comment: @RobinEkman can you please explain it a bit further?

Answer (score 2):

How about you just take

$r_n = \text{the first $n$ decimal digits of $\sqrt 2$}$

Answer (score 1):

What about sequence defined by $u_0 = 1$ and $u_{n+1} = \frac{u_n + \frac{2}{u_n}}{2}$ for $n\in\mathbf{N}$ which is convergent in $\mathbf{R}$ to a square root of $2$ so that it is cauchy in $\mathbf{R}$ and also in $\mathbf{Q}$, and whose limit can't be rational. It is an elementary example as, whatevers tastes may be, it is *quicker* to prove its convergence and the irrationality of its limit (in $\mathbf{R}$) than to do it for $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$...